# Is Non-Euclidean geometry really "Non"?

Tags: geometry, axioms, noneuclidean-geometry

[image]
The definition of a straight line according to google.

I do not understand why I call these geometries "non-Euclidean". In my view, both hyperbolic and elliptical geometry are just a dimensional reference change of the plane, using the same elements described by Euclid. Both are described by curved planes, that is, analyzed three-dimensionaly. A straight line is no longer a straight line. Perhaps there is a lost axiom that has not been introduced to better define what a line is and not to confuse it with a curve.
What I want to mean is that, all of these are the same elements but with another perspective. If we can define what a line really is, maybe we can debunk the axioms denying the parallels axiom.
If anyone has understood my doubt, please tell me where I am wrong or if there is truth in my words. Thanks.

Comment: In euclidean geometry the parallel postulate holds, in non-euclidean ones it doesn't. I doubt "dimensional reference change" and/or "analyzed three dimensionality" mean anything... The reason non-euclidean geometries are non-euclidean is extremely concrete and simple.

Comment: I suggest you read a modern exposition of euclidean geometry. Axioms do not define what a line is, for example —lines are undefined concepts, and that is in fact most of the point!

Comment: I think by "analyzed three dimensionally," he means that they have models which can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Where can I find such modern exposition, Mrs. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez?

Comment: There are many books with title "introduction to non-euclidean geometry", you can probably learn the basics from anyone of them. One of them has Coxeter as author, and nothing recommends a book more than that.

Comment: If Lucky's comment is a correct interpretation of your motivation, it's worth noting that the [hyperbolic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) **cannot** in fact be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$; this is [due to Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)).

Comment: But the parallel axiom is precisely the thing that "defines what a line really is" (in the sense that it disallows non-euclidean interpretations where the "lines" are not straight lines.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So, the non-euclidean geometry doesn't work with lines, but with another element. This new element needs the axiom of parallels working, to exist, because his own axiom is the denial of the first one. Does this make sense?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, that is simply not true. There are models of euclidean geometry in which lines are not straight lines. A stupid way to get one is to find any bijection of the plane onto itself which does not preserve straight lines, and define a line to be the image of a usual line under that bijection. There are other, more clever models in which the plane is the inside of a disc, for example, and lines are parts of ellipses.

Comment: @nicolas, you should **really** read up a bit about what euclidean and non-euclidean geometry actually is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I agree that I'm technically wrong here, just trying to refute the second to last sentence of the post in a way that doesn't get too into the details

Comment: You cannot refute what is a technical point being technically wrong.

Comment: @nicolas, in particular, if you re trying to "debunk" something in this context, you should really study the subject. There is nothing to debunk, there has not been anything to debunk for almost a 100 years now...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I didn't find OP's point to be a paragon of technicality, but I'll accede that making incorrect statements isn't the way to go.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes, I know, I'm asking in that way to understand more what geometry is on its logical language. I'll find some good books and study. Thanks.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I agree with <<But the parallel axiom is precisely the thing that "defines what a line really is" (in the sense that it disallows non-euclidean interpretations where the "lines" are not straight lines.)>>

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen For Euclid a straight line is made by first specifying two points and then drawing a line through the two points. This is stated clearly in his first postulate and it used in HIS formulation of 5th postulate and through out the Elements. Non-Euclidean geometry presumes this is "equivalent" to first making a line through a given point and then picking a second point on the line. However, this way of making a line is only functionally equivalent rather than logically equivalent to Euclid's way.  If it were logically equivalent it would not give rise to consistent alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this **comment** is to illustrate that the concept of "being straight" is only a psychological one.

The figure below depicts the Klein model of the hyperbolic geometry within which the Euclidean plane can be modelled. Here the half ellipses centered at the center of the Klein circle tangent to the same are the Euclidean straights. And the hyperbolic straights "look straight".

The solid lines are Euclidean and the broken lines are hyperbolic. In this "Orthus" model the Euclidean and the hyperbolic geometry live together.

[image]

Native Hyperboleans will find the Euclidean straights to be funny and curved while the Euclideans will find the hyperbolic straights to be funny and curved.

The question: "Who is right?" is completely meaningless.